# How to pass shared_ptr to naked ptr function

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-ptr, ownership

I have an `Entity` class defined by a lib, and `Registry` which is class that manages Entities registered to it with a map.

What i'm trying to do:

```
//Registry Signature
void Registry::add(Entity* entity);


//my function (IGameEntity subclasses Entity)
void GameLogic::addEntity(shared_ptr<IGameEntity> entity, GameEntityId id) {
 GameEntityId entityId = entity->getId();
 gameEntities.push_back(entity);
 Framework::Registry::instance()->add(entity); //<-- this doesn't work
}
```

I'm trying to figure how to handle this, since i'm keeping shared_ptr's and then i'm gonna have to pass a pointer.

Another thing is that if the registry gets destroyed by some reason it will call `delete` on all entities remaining in the map.

If i pass `entity` has `weak_ptr<Entity>(entity)` it works but i'm not fully grasping whats going on in terms of what will happen if `Registry` calls delete on a weak_ptr.

And if i pass `entity` has `entity.get()` what will happen when the reference count reaches zero or the registry tries to delete it.

Comment: You're purely at an impasse because your design is contradictory. `shared_ptr` very specifically and purposefully owns the resource. The registry needs to either work with that (luckily you're already using a `shared_ptr` so that's easy), or not claim ownership at all. Either way, the fact it calls `delete` is the issue.

Comment: You clearly need to define what your ownership semantics are. You say `Registry` *manages* the entities, however, it seems your `GameLogic` also stores the `shared_ptr`s to those entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two incompatible ownership schemes.

You need to either change one of them, or clone the object that should be transferred from one scheme to the other.

There is a trick for releasing a `shared_ptr` when there is only one reference to the object. But you don't want to do that. Even if you know enough about the insides of the library to do it.

So, as a practical solution, change the registry thing.

Make it take a `shared_ptr`.